# WebMatrix extension: possible to write to error list and output pane?

Tags: xaml, webmatrix

I'm currently writing a WebMatrix extension for version 2.0. I have a process I want to execute and have the output stream to an output pane, and have errors parsed to the error list. Any way to do this automatically, or access the Error List through an object model? Can't find anything in documentation or with ILSpy on Microsoft.WebMatrix.Extensibility assembly.

If this would not work, the only "workarround" I see is to open a XAML window, and redirect the output from the process to this window. This window could have an error list included as well.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, right now there isn't a way to get access to the error list through the SDK (we're working on that).  One thing you can do is create your own tab down in the task panel and pipe your errors to that.  Have a look at the example of [adding/managing a tab in the task panel](https://github.com/microsoftwebmatrix/nodepowertools).

Specifically, check out [WebMatrixExtension.cs](https://github.com/MicrosoftWebMatrix/NodePowerTools/blob/master/NodePowerTools/WebMatrixExtension.cs).

Hopefully this helps!